# jquery Flot Chart - How to hide weekend datetimes - for Forex charts?

Tags: jquery, charts, flot, forex

How can I hide the Weekend times on X-axis? This timeline should skip the time between the Friday 23:59 and Monday 00:00 - i.e. all the Weekend.

I already skipped all timestamps between Friday evening and Monday morning, but it still shows the data like it there is some activity during a Weekend.

[image]

```js
var data = [
   { data: EUR, label: "EUR" },
   { data: USD, label: "USD" },
   { data: CAD, label: "CAD" },
   { data: GBP, label: "GBP" },
   { data: CHF, label: "CHF" },
   { data: AUD, label: "AUD" },
   { data: NZD, label: "NZD" },
   { data: JPY, label: "JPY" }
  ];

  $.plot("#chart", data, {
   series: {
    lines:  { show: true },
    points: { show: true }
   },
   xaxis: {
                                mode:       "time",
                                timeformat: "%d/%m %H"
                        },
   yaxis: {
    ticks:       10,
    min:        -45,
    max:         45,
    tickDecimals: 1
   },
                        grid: { 
                               clickable: 1,
                               hoverable: 1,
                               backgroundColor: { colors: [ "#fff", "#eee" ] },
                               borderWidth: {
                                              top:    1,
                                              right:  1,
                                              bottom: 2,
                                              left:   2
                               }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible with the use of the transform properties for the xaxis (see the documentation [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes)). I build a fiddle showing it for a simple case [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9p4vw77j/). But for a time series you have somewhat more to do.

I will leave this here as a starting point and may come back and expand it when I have time. Relevant code:

```
var x_min = 0;
var x_max = 30;
var x_break_interval = 10;
var x_break_on = 5;
var x_break_size = 4;

// ...

xaxis: {
    tickSize: 5,
    transform: function(value) {
        var shift = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= value / x_break_interval; i++) {
            shift++;
        }
        return value - (shift * x_break_size);
    },
    inverseTransform: function(value) {
        var shift = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= x_max / x_break_interval; i++) {
            if (value > (i + 1) * (x_break_on + x_break_size)) {
                shift++;
            }
        }
        return value + (shift * x_break_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, while the idea is clear, the Trading World is not so simple, Sir. No one  transform-er can implement ad-hoc mandatory Market close(s), so the easiest path is not granted by design ( ref. the answer on both an adequate & robust-enough solution of the subject problem >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149127 ).

Answer (score 0):

### This is solved by using contiguous `ordinal`#s instead of datetimes

Using `ordinal`-s for X and their indirect-reference to another { array | generator } for showing the actual X-axis label values.

Yes, that simple.

[image]

Market open-times are principally neither contiguous, nor deterministic / predictable - besides trading Terms & Conditions ( and their changes ), besides regular banking and/or local holidays, there are also administrative mandatory ad-hoc ( responsive ) market-close(s) ( hopefully just for a few selected trading instruments, under some extreme ( typically very extreme ) market conditions ) et al.

So no one knows beforehand...

One simply has to **stop using any other than pure ordinal numbers for X-axis**, resulting in a pure, contiguous sequence of numbers ( the ordinals ), thus enumerating all the discrete units of "allowable"-time quanta ( be it days, hours, minutes ( if trading on larger time-frames ), seconds, milliseconds ( see FIX-Protocol API specification ) or even the highest speeds in FX HFT trading interfaces - still there are discrete values in TimeDOMAIN -- thus enumerable by ordinals ).

Once your data reflects the reality in using per-se the ordinal number indexing, the next step is to add one more serie -- again, coherently indexed as the ordinal-number indices for PriceDOMAIN data-series -- now, containing the adequate TimeDOMAIN ( human-readable ) values, that will be shown in the X-axis GUI-display visualisations.

This has been **de-facto standard in GUI-designs since the earliest days, and will sure remain such** for both the simplicity of the concept ( the ordinal-indexed sequence of "permissible" values ) and the separation of concerns.

**`matplotlib`** and many other graphing packages use this for several decades and so will newer graphing tools.